# nodemon "restarting due to changes..." repeatedly displays in VSCode and slows down every restarting process

Tags: visual-studio-code, nodemon

I use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) version 1.18.9 (Latest version as of today).

I use Visual Studio Code (VSCode). I open a terminal and execute `nodemon dev-server.js` but it displays this repeatedly

> restarting due to changes...

as follows

[image: nodemon-restarting]

and after a few seconds it will complete its restarting process.

I use Windows 10.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

package.json

```
   {
      "scripts": {
        "nodemon": "nodemon dev-server.js"
      },
    }
```

start nodemon by npm

```
$ npm run nodemon
save dev-server.js file, nodemon will restart twice
```

start nodemon direct

```
$ nodemon dev-server.js
save dev-server.js file, nodemon is all right

osx 10.11.3
nodemon 1.9.2
```

=============UPDATED ANSWER FROM COMMENTS======================

updating answer from comments as logic from comments worked for this problem.

try adding delay for some time. let me know if it works. 
`nodemon lib/dev-server.js --delay 1` ..

whatever your directory is.

Comment: What exactly do I need to do?

Comment: Remove ~/.node-gyp folder and rebuild fsevent fix the issue. Are you on mac OSX?

Comment: Ok, try adding delay for some time. let me know if it works. nodemon lib/dev-server.js --delay 1 .. whatever your directory is.

Comment: Adding --delay 1 works. I tried it but I want a way to just use the command as what it should be used. Like just nodemon dev-server.js. I don't want to remember adding  --delay 1 everytime I need to do this. I will just wait for possible better solutions. If there is none then I will accept this at the end.

Comment: Ok, well this is hillareous, but have you tried to remove the global installation of the nodemon, and reinstall it. 

npm uninstall -g nodemon
npm install -g nodemon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186899/discussion-between-jabongg-and-holydragon).

Comment: This `--delay 1` works on starting the process. After several days of working on it, it still tends to give some repeating restart text but not as many as before. So, it doesn't entirely solve the problem. It is proved to solve the part when I call it but not when it actually detects changes and restarts itself.

Comment: try increasing delay time for some more seconds then. It's just a hack brother.

Comment: Sure. I think this is the only working workaround here so far. So please update your answer to include --delay and explanation about it so other people who have this problem will easily find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have to change the settings on the VSCode, go to File->Auto Save(unmark the option). After that the project will restart only when you use ctrl+s on the specific path.

---

Edit: I did some tests on my computer and I reproduced what you trying to mean, probably you are trying to use diferent extensions that nodemon does not support.
 Take a look on this part of the [documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon):

> Specifying extension watch list By default, nodemon looks for files
>   with the .js, .mjs, .coffee, .litcoffee, and .json extensions. If you
>   use the --exec option and monitor app.py nodemon will monitor files
>   with the extension of .py. However, you can specify your own list with
>   the -e (or --ext) switch like so:
>
> nodemon -e js,jade Now nodemon will restart on any changes to files in
>   the directory (or subdirectories) with the extensions .js, .jade.

try to run `nodemon -e ts,json(all extensions that you want to be listener) dev-server.js`. When I removed the extension I got the same issue of you.

Comment: Could you send to me the exact nodemon script? Maybe you have to set the watching using --watch.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by nodemon script. I only execute this command (`nodemon dev-server.js`) in the VSCode terminal.

Comment: Do you really need to listenner the whole application? Try to add the --watch tag to specify the path to be listener.

Try: `nodemon --watch someFolder/someFile --exec dev-server.js` or `nodemon dev-server.js --watch someFolder/someFile`

Comment: Yes, I want to watch the whole application. I tried what you suggested with the --watch thing but it doesn't work. It still runs as what I posted in the question even when this nodemon is the only thing that is running on this whole project.

Comment: Tried `nodemon -e js,json dev-server.js`. Doesn't work. It still displays lots of repeating restart text.

Comment: Also I don't have any extensions installed in the VSCode.

Comment: I am not sure, but I would say that there is an issue with nodemon and Windows 10.

I have the same problems, and as far as I can remember, I never had problems in earlier versions of Windows.

Just my €0.02

Ad

Answer (score 1):

please set Windows Environment Path

1. Right Click PC/My Computer
2. Properties
3. Environment
4. Path --> Edit --> New
5. Paste:- C:\Windows\System32

ok
then restart VSCode

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to build your application without using nodemon
2. Correct the errors, which may be the result of tslint being unable to fix something and generating a syntax error
3. Restart your application with nodemon

Answer (score 0):

I guess you using typescript on your code. All time dist folder update nodemon restart again and again. So I fix it adding package.json file this code block:

"nodemonConfig": {
"ext": "js",
"ignore": [
"*.test.ts",
"db/*",
"dist"
],
"delay": "2"
}

So this ignore the dist folder and not restarting again and again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).